# SharePoint Designer 2013 cannot add new linked data source

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to add a new *Linked Data Source* using SharePoint Designer 2013, I click on "Configure Linked Source" and it does nothing.

I tried to add in a page an empty `Data View`, and when I click "Data Source Details", Designer **crashes.**

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but I'm not sure if there is really an impediment to use this feature on SharePoint 2013.

Is it possible to use *Linked Data Sources* on SharePoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After some trial and error, I got it to work after I named all the Data sources uniquely.

Open the Linked Data Sources dialog in SPD 2013. 
Switch to the General tab and enter something for the name, description, and keywords. The name you use here will show up under "Linked Sources" when you are done.

Switch to the Source tab and open Configure Linked Source...
Pick the sources you want
Select the type of link (Join / Merge)
Click Finish

You should see the sources in the Component Source Properties list. 
Edit the properties for each data source
SharePoint gives them all the default name "Data Source" -- seems like this is where the problem was/is -- they all have the same name.

After I gave each a unique name (and description and keywords), it worked.